# How to have a hook and have a timer running at the same time?

Tags: c, while-loop, timer, setwindowshookex, keyhook

I am trying to write a macro program in C and I have managed to get the keys with the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK _hook;

KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) {
            printf("Key %lu pressed.\n", kbdStruct.vkCode);
        } else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) {
            printf("Key %lu released.\n", kbdStruct.vkCode);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void main() {
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to install hook!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {}
}
```

I want the program to press a sequence of keys on specific times with `SendInput()` function when a specific key is pressed.
The `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook is not called anymore when the while loop is set to infinite.
Also using `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)` does not seem to be clean to me.

I have searched for a hook method to call a function on a given interval but without success.

I use the GNU GCC compiler.

I have almost no experience in programming in C on the computer but I do have experience in programming in C for microcontrollers.

Edit:

I have tried the method with SetTimer() but it does not get called.
I have used the example from this page: http://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/set-timer.php

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TimerID 85

HHOOK _hook;

KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

VOID __stdcall MyTimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
    printf("Timer call\n");
}

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) {
            printf("Key %lu pressed.\n", kbdStruct.vkCode);
        } else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) {
            printf("Key %lu released.\n", kbdStruct.vkCode);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void main() {
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to install hook!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    SetTimer(NULL, TimerID, 1000, MyTimerProc);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {}
}
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with Windows but looked up “winapi timers using messages” and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers, which looks like it might be right.

Comment: You want to use `SetTimer()` like @Ry- posted above, but you want to use it with the 4th parameter (`TIMERPROC`) filled in. That would be a callback to a method with this signature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-timerproc

Comment: Is `SetTimer` failing? Can you call `GetLastError()` after you call `SetTimer`? What does `SetTimer` return?

Comment: With `DWORD dw = GetLastError(); printf("Error code is %X", dw);` I get 7E wich is the same as when I remove `SetTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it ages, but from what I remember `SetTimer` relies on a Wndproc or Timerproc callback that looks for `WM_TIMER` messages. "Windows timers" are pretty crude overall though, so I would stay away from them.

What you should do instead is to create a thread which does the job. You can have it effectively asleep most of the time with `WaitForMultipleObjects` that allows you to define a timeout. When it times out, perform the task that should repeated cyclically. You should also create two custom events (`CreateEvent` etc), one that is sent from the hook callback informing the thread of an update ("next time you work, do work x instead"), and another that tells the threat to gracefully shut itself down (end of program etc). With this design you don't have to worry about re-entrancy either.